# Redirect url to other on router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

Example: If I go to https://www.google.com/ I would like my router to send me to https://www.example.com/.

So if I download this image https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png I would like it to download this one https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uT5_V-V0UyPwNja3HgoqjyERKVejFNWrsPaJwkIX5YOnUOEK6PtyEouUxgMpd7rdg0oY7TX-U5v4M59ntFLMawq8oaE97YaJhtfrO1kDHHBfInrVIg=w1440-rj-l170

Etc...

Comment: This likely isn't possible with most routers. This probably needs to be done with a web proxy of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

The first part: in principle yes, but in practice it might not be really worth the trouble.

To achieve the first part, you can edit your hosts file so that [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) points to whatever IP address you want it to direct you to. Or you can configure your own private DNS server to do the same. The first option will affect only you, the second option will affect also your visitors who might want to use the internet through your Wi-Fi.

This will redirect all requests to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). Not requests to its subdomains like maps.google.com or images.google.com which have separate DNS records - you will need to create separate rule for each subdomain.

Second option is just no. Not with basic routing anyway, and not without an absolutely insane amount of work. You would need to create a redirection for every single image / logo you want to change.

Even that's not guaranteed to give the result you're looking for. Your redirection will be valid exactly as long as the original image location and name stay the same. As soon as Google decides to move the original from `.../1x/` to `.../common/` or just changes the name redirection will fail.

---

That's not to say your end goal is unacievable. If you explain the purpose of the exercise, usually a way can be found.

Comment: It is to change the url of Autoconfiguration URL with proxy to block iboss